# Test purchase on android

Tags: android, libgdx, in-app-purchase

I´ve succesfully implemented a purchase flow for my app. 
My app is published in Alpha stage with two of my google accounts listed as testaccounts. The APK published is the same installed on my phone.

Though, when I try purchasing something I get the "Authentication is required, please log in to you google account".
So what I did was 1. removed all my accounts on my phone and re-logged them. 2.Cleared all the data of the Play store. 3.Uninstalled the latest update(Incase it was the new update playing fuzzy).
Still the same error. 
Someone that can help me? Really dont want to release the app without testing the purchasing..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, I got rid of this message by creating Google Group (https://groups.google.com) and adding my test accounts there. Then go to Google Play Developer Console, Your app -> APK -> Alpha testers and choose "Manage list of testers". There, add just created Google Group, and share a link to your app (appears below) with your test account. Next, open that link from email on your test device, and follow instructions (you will need to login in Chrome on mobile).

For reference:
[image]

Comment: I took a look. But it says " The link for the testers will be created when the app is published" ?? Do I need to publish the app anyways?

Comment: Yes, the app needs to be **published** (not just uploaded) to Alpha. Then once you have the group created, with the link for testers (your test accounts), you'll be able to test.

Comment: Well I got all green on APK, Prices etc.. and it says "Ready for publish" but if I publish it, it disappears from the Beta section?

Comment: You said you have it in Alpha, yes? Publish in Alpha, and add Google Group, with those 2 email addresses you use for testing. Then send yourself links to app, and you will be able to test. You are not publishing it in Production yet (just Alpha, or Beta), so it won't be visible to general public, only to members of your Google Group.